# Browser crashes while binding 25k-100k records

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In one of the application, I need a grid to load 100k records without pagination by using Kendo Grid virtualization.

Technologies used: SQL server 2012, asp.net web app, angular.

I have 15 columns in the grid, up to 10K records, browser is loading between 20,000-100,000 records and the browser crashes.

Can I bind 100k records in a Kendo Grid without pagination?
Is there any other way to load the 100k records without pagination?

What is the maximum data size browsers (Chrome, Firefox) support?

Comment: Don't load so many records at once, load records when you display them. In my opinion even 1k is too much. 100k makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

According to: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/virtualization-local-data 
They loaded 500K with 5 columns. If you notice in the code they do limit to smaller data on certain browsers. It likely comes down to JavaScript memory and how fast JS can process the volume.

My recommendation:

1. Use the Grid with server pagination, but also allow server sorting and filtering. I used OData for this at 100 rows at a time, makes the server part easy.
2. Offer the option to export the data to CSV or Excel.

Comment: Note, if using current OData, make sure to use the type: "odata-v4" and any queries in Google add v4 to the search. OData has a lot of breaking changes between v2 and v4.

Comment: i have seen the demo before i have asking the question to StackOverflow.its working fine with your people.js and have tested for  added 15 columns.

The problem only occurs.
we are using webapi,But inside the Webapi, they are retrieving the data by using  stored-procedures by Ado.net commands and the response pass via angular.

i am not using OData, just web API return those response binding via angular promises to bind with.
Note: My Requirement is Dont have pagination. need to bind the data  1k grid without affecting exsiting framework.

What you are suggesting?